# How can an Android Activity use a Knopflerfish OSGi Bundle installed on the device

Tags: android, osgi, knopflerfish

I have installed Knopflerfish on an Android emulator using this tutorial: http://www.knopflerfish.org/releases/current/docs/android_dalvik_tutorial.html

The installation on the emulator is ok, and now I would like to call an OSGi bundle running on the emulator from my Android Activity. But I just can't find any way to do this.

Is there somebody who has already done such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?

http://nilvec.com/embedding-osgi-into-an-android-application-part-1.html

The patches I submitted for better Android/Dalvik support in Knopflerfish have been merged so patching and recompiling KF should not be necessary anymore:

http://knopflerfish.blogspot.hu/2012/07/knopflerfish-33-released.html

I haven't tested this myself, though.

Comment: how can I use the latest release of Knopflerfish SDK in my app? I thought I only need "framework.jar". What are the difference between the two? And how can I get the latest release of "framework.jar"?

What I did is to download "framework.jar" from this link http://www.knopflerfish.org/releases/3.2/docs/jars/framework.html
but it didn't work with Android.

See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037496/embedding-knopflerfish-in-android-doesnt-work#_=_

Comment: Not really, I thought I started my bundle, but It didn't really start. Though, no errors show. See this @Idx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263747/starting-a-bundle-on-knopflerfish-embedded-into-android-doesnt-work